# How to map to an object using the values of an array of object?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i have the following json response

```
[{ country: string, code: string}]
```

now i would like to create an object with `array.map(x => {[x.country]: false})`
only the syntax `[]` to use the value of country as a key does not work.
the purpose is to have a dynamic checkbox group fetched from the backend
How do map the array to `{ "country": false }`

Answer (score 0):

The brackets behind the arrow belong to the function and not to the object you try to create.

Add either ()

```
array.map(x => ({[x.country]: false}))
```

or a return value.

```
array.map(x => {
  return {[x.country]: false};
})
```